# Get a new array with column values from two different arrays in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I have two array values

```
loncountries[index] = [80.2116001, 80.173399]
latcountries[index] = [13.042699, 13.0409047]
```

Now I want them in a new Array like

```
loncountries[index] = [13.042699,80.2116001]
latcountries[index] = [13.0409047,80.173399]
```

Just the first columns as a new Array. Also I am fetcihg it from Sqlite Database and attaching the code below. Is it possible to do it during fetching from db.

```
String[] latcountries;
String[] loncountries;
if (cJoin != null) {
int countJoin = cJoin.getCount();

if (countJoin > 0) {
    latcountries = new String[countJoin];
    loncountries = new String[countJoin];
    int index = 0;
    cJoin.moveToFirst();

    while (!cJoin.isAfterLast()) {
        loncountries[index] = cJoin.getString(0);
        latcountries[index] = cJoin.getString(1);
        index++;
        cJoin.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach could be to declare a *bean-like* class,

```
public class Position {
   public String mLat;
   public String mLon;
}
```

and then declare an array of position:

```
Position[] latLon = new Position[countJoin];
```

at every iteration then

```
 while (!cJoin.isAfterLast()) {
     Position p = new Position();
     p.mLat = cJoin.getString(1);
     p.mLon = cJoin.getString(0);
     latLon[index++] = p;
 }
```